# Is there a nice expression for the number of lattice points on a sphere?

Tags: co.combinatorics, nt.number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a simple way to compute the number of ways to write a positive integer as the sum of three squares?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3596/is-there-a-simple-way-to-compute-the-number-of-ways-to-write-a-positive-integer-a)

Is there a nice expression for the number of points in $\mathbb{Z}^3$ which lie a distance of $\sqrt{n}$ from the origin? Here, $n$ is of course a positive integer.

Comment: Let me rephrase your question as follows: is there a closed form expression for the cube of the theta series, $\bigl(\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}q^{n^2}\bigr)^3$. The answer is "no", although for a very close cube, $\bigl(\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}(-1)^nq^{(6n+1)^2/24}\bigr)^3$, one has $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(2n+1)q^{(2n+1)^2/8}$. 

Comment: @Wadim: the poster did not ask for a closed form expression, he asked for a "nice expression". Firstly, can you really assert with confidence that there is no "closed form expression"? And secondly, so much is known about the generating function---it spans the space of level 4 weight 3/2 modular forms, and there are surely by now computer algebra packages which efficiently compute coefficients---that one might argue that "it's the coefficient of q^n in the unique normalised weight 3/2 level 4 modular form, and a lot is known about coeffs of modular forms" is a "nice expression" for the number!

Comment: @Kevin, I should agree that being an object of modular origin is already being a nice object. Many of them possess "nice expressions" which in the context of the problem seems to mean "easily computable". The nicest form I could suggest in this case is $f(q)=\bigl(\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}q^{n^2}\bigr)^3$ for the generating function. I can also add that because of the modular origin the series $f(q)$ satisfies an algebraic differential equation; by means of $q\dfrac d{dq}$ this DE has constant coefficients. This could be a very practical way to compute $f(q)$!

Comment: @Kevin: another level 4 weight 3/2 modular form, linearly independent with $f(q)$, is $\bigl(\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}(-1)^nq^{n^2}\bigr)^3$.

Comment: See my answer http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3596/is-there-a-simple-way-to-compute-the-number-of-ways-to-write-a-positive-integer-a

Comment: @Wadim: I think the form you think has level 4, has level 16. Maybe it depends on normalisations or something? Magma is telling me that the space of weight 3/2 forms of level 4 has dimension 1.

Comment: @Kevin: You are right, the space of level 4 weight 3/2 MFs is 1 dimensional. @David: Thanks for the link to the earlier question! Your answer there is indeed exhaustive enough.

Comment: @David: Thanks for directing me to your answer; it was very helpful.

Comment: @Kevin: since this is an exact duplicate and you already got some very nice answers, I hope you don't mind my voting to close.  

Answer (score 4):

We (me, Michel, and Venkatesh) write something about this question in the preprint  ["Linnik's Ergodic method and the distribution of integral points on spheres."](http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.0897)

In particular, in section 3 we explain how when n is squarefree and not congruent to 7 mod 8 the solution set of x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = n (up to the natural SO_3(Z) action) is naturally a torsor for a certain class group, so that in particular the size of the set is equal to the size of the class group.  None of this is really original to us, I should emphasize!  Maybe the use of the word "torsor," at most.

Answer (score 2):

There is one answer to your question that is classical, discovered by Dirichlet. The number of proper representations of $n$ as a sum of three squares can be expressed as a sum of Jacobi symbols, for example 
$$
r_3'(n) = 24\sum_{m \leq n/4}\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)
$$
if $n \equiv 1{\;}(4)$. Here $r_3'(n)$ denotes the number of proper representations, where 
$x,y,z$ in $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = n$ has no common factor. If $n$ is squarefree then $r_3(n) = r_3'(n)$, otherwise $r_3(n)$ is given by a sum 
$$
r_3(n) = \sum_{d^2|n}r_3'(n/d^2)
$$
The above formula strongly suggests that there is no simple closed form expression for $r_3(n)$.

Whether this answer really qualifies as nice is uncertain. It is necessary to separate into cases. The formula looks slightly different when $n \equiv 3{\;}(4)$. How it looks when $n$ is even I do not know.

I should mention that Gauss had expressed the number of proper representations of $n$ as a sum of three squares in terms of class numbers of  binary quadratic forms. Dirichlet obtained his formulas for $r_3'(n)$ by applying his class number formula.