# Is there an exact  formula of the number of ways to represent n=2x^2+y^2+z^2?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Is there an exact  formula of the number of ways to represent n=2x^2+y^2+z^2?
x,y,z are all integers or all are half integers.

Comment: Yes. The ternary form in question is the only of its genus. So unless there aren't any representations ($n=2*4^n*(8k+7)$), their number is a small multiple of the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2n})$ (usually 4, more if $n$ isn't squarefree (need to count forms in non-maximal order and non-primitive forms)). This is pretty standard, and a search for "ternary quadratic forms" brings up some good articles. I suggest getting the $x^2+y^2+z^2$ case first.

Comment: See answers to 
$$ $$
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3596/is-there-a-simple-way-to-compute-the-number-of-ways-to-write-a-positive-integer-a/22655#22655 
$$ $$
Dror's comment is what I referred to as the approach of Jones.


Comment: Thanks for Dror's answer! For the case $ n=x^2+y^2+z^2$, the formula is very classical. For the other cases,  I think it maybe have a close relation with the class number of $\Q(\sqrt{-2n})$. However I could not find a formula, even for the very simple case $n=2x^2+y^2+z^2$. Could someone give a formula? Thank you!