# Primes sum ratio

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let

$$G(n)=\begin{cases}1 &\mbox{if }n \mbox{ is a prime }\equiv 3\bmod17\\0&\mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

And let

$$P(n)=\begin{cases}1 &\mbox{if }n \mbox{ is a prime }\\0&\mbox{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Then
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{n=1}^N G(n)}{\sum\limits_{n=1}^N P(n)}=1/\varphi(17)=\frac1{16}$$
With $\varphi(b)$ Euler's totient function

What is 
$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{\sum\limits_{n=1}^N n\,G(n)}{\sum\limits_{n=1}^N n\,P(n)}?$$

And what is O(f(n)) of the the fastest growing function f(n) such that

$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{\sum\limits_{n=1}^N f(n)G(n)}{\sum\limits_{n=1}^N f(n)P(n)}=converges$$

Comment: Please provide some motivation for this question. In the absence of motivation I vote to close; but might reconsider if motivation is provided.

Comment: Due to the narrow timeline it is not clear to me whether your edit is a repsonse to my request. In any case, it does not address my consern. 
Why do you want to know this? As opposed to say the analog question for 5 and 19 instead of 3 and 17.

Comment: Just use Siegel–Walfisz and summation by parts: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel%E2%80%93Walfisz_theorem

Comment: @kermit: Some general info on what motivated you to ask this question; implictly this includes some information on your general knowledge of Analytic Numb. Th. (and mathematics more generally). Are you a. an expert on this and there is some subtlety we miss, b. are you some researcher in a different field that happened to come across this problem for some reason, c. are you just studying or have studied some analytic number theory and are asking additional question, d. have you never studied an. NT and are modifying some statements you saw somewhere... (except for a. and b. I suggest math.SE)

Comment: @quid Ok then d. Where should I start if I want to learn everything we know and dont know about the prime numbers and their distribution? Is there any good papers or books that deals exclusively with prime numbers? And covers everything

Comment: Two explict suggestions for introduction: Apostol 'Introduction to Analytic Number Theory' and Tenenbaum and Mendes France 'The prime numbers and their distribution' (whose title is exactly what you ask for), 

For an overview on more material see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/71453/what-should-be-learned-in-an-introductory-analytic-number-theory-course 

I am not sure what you mean 'covers everything': this is a huge field I do not think there is any one book that covers everything and more recent developments do not exist in book form at all.